# Text formula with fixed horizontal limits

Tags: equations

I would like to write a formula of the form

$$
A = B \times C
$$

where $A$ is some long phrase, e.g., ``the marginal utility of doing so and so given that we know this and that'', and $B$ and $C$ are similar phrases. The problem is that the texts $A,B,C$ extend to the right, and I would like to restrict each to be about 1/4 of the horizontal length of the page, and would like to allow them to extend downwards for as much space as needed to fit the phrase. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\begin{array}{P}
the marginal utility of doing so and so given this and that
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{P}
the marginal utility of doing so and so given this and that
\end{array}\right)
\times
\left(\begin{array}{P}
the marginal utility of doing so and so given this and that
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

The `P` column type that's use inside each of the three `array` environments is defined to take up a width of `0.25\textwidth`, it allows automatic line wrapping, and it typesets its contents ragged-right (rather than fully-justified) while allowing hyphenation. If hyphenation is not appropriate, replace `\RaggedRight` with `\raggedright`. If you want the material centered instead of raggedright, replace `\RaggedRight` with `\Centering` (or `\raggedright` with `\centering`).

Comment: You can use `tabular`, instead of `array`.

Comment: @egreg - But `tabular` inserts `\tabcolsep` (6pt) of whitespace at both edges, whereas `array` inserts `\arraycolsep` (5pt). The smaller amount of whitespace seems better (to me at least).

Comment: Is there any way to make the arrays shrink in size if the text is smaller than 1/4 of the page? (marginal utility ...) = (short phrase) \times (marginal utility ...)?

Comment: @Ben - To typeset a "short phrase" -- which I assume is something that fits on a single line with a width of less than `0.25\textwidth` -- I would simply write `(\mbox{short phrase})`. If you've loaded the `amsmath` package, you could use `\text` instead of `\mbox`. If the parentheses that surround the short phrase look a bit puny, use `\bigl(` or even `\Bigl(` instead of `(`, and `\bigr)` or `\Bigr)` instead of `)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\[
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{something...}
=
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{something...}
\times
\parbox{.25\textwidth}{something...}
\]
```